# Tune2fs utility in e2fsprogs reserve block count is reset to a default state in Development Board

Tags: linux, filesystems

Tune2fs utility in e2fsprogs reserve block count is reset to a default value in Development Board. But in market released product like GS2 and GS3 reserve block count is not reset to default value. Why?

I have used the following command in both target and Commercial device.
$ tune2fs -m 25 /dev/block/mmcblk0p5 ---- To set 25% reserved block count.
$ df –B 4096 /dev/block/mmcblk0p5   ---- To read the Used space, available space and Free space.
$ tune2fs -l /dev/block/mmcblk0p5     ---- To check the Reserved block count.

Comment: It is virtually impossible to answer this question unless you tell more about the problem - like commands you have executed, versions, some logs, also what makes your dev board different from released board. Remember - we cannot read your screen, much less your mind.

Comment: I have used the following command in both target and Commercial device.
$ tune2fs -m 25 /dev/block/mmcblk0p5 ---- To set 25% reserved block count.
$ df –B 4096 /dev/block/mmcblk0p5   ---- To read the Used space, available space and Free space.
$ tune2fs -l /dev/block/mmcblk0p5     ---- To check the Reserved block count.